# insert row in section with alertview

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am creating an app `tableview` based.

On `tableview` i have 6 sections. Under those sections there are some rows.

Also i have `UIButtons` on each section.

Now when i click the `UIButton` on a particular section it will call an alert with textfield. When i type row name and press ok it will insert the row in that particular section. I have created alert with textfield. But when i try the rest it does not show up the row. What do i do??? I have been stuck in this for a couple of days.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what u have already tried ? post here..

Comment: well.....i couldn't try anything.....my arrays are mutable in nature and static....

Comment: if (section_number== 0)
        {
            
            [self.socialdata addObject:rowTextTF.text];
            [self.websitesList reloadData];
        }
till this i could do.....where section_number is an integer and indexpath.section has been assigned to it.socialdata is one of my 6 arrays.

Comment: Post your code for cellForRowAtIndexPath. That will be helpful to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting or removing any row or section in your tableView then you need to update your tableView's dataSource and then populate through it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method by calling `[self.tableView reloadData].